# Adding suffix to thousands of cells VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What is an efficient way of adding a suffix (in this case simply "ID") to thousands of cells (500,000 cells) using VBA?

The simple and usual 'for loop' in VBA takes far too long. (e.g.  `For Each Cell In Selection.Cells` etc. takes tens of minutes for the number of cells).

I've written this below (based off internet searches), and works on Excel 365, but not on Excel 2016. Instead, in 2016 it takes the top left cell and just pastes that across all selected cells. Any thoughts on how to rectify this? Many thanks.

```
Sub AddTextToEndOfCellValue()
Dim Suffix As String
Suffix = "ID"
Selection = Evaluate(Replace("REPLACE(@,LEN(@)+1,0,""" & Suffix & """)", "@", Selection.Address))
Selection.Replace Suffix, "", xlWhole, , , , False, False
End Sub
```

[input and expected output sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYQit.png)

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, Please add a screen shot/ sample of your data and result you are expecting.

Comment: Hi Naresh, thanks for your comment. I've attached a sample input and expected output for a sample of cells to the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only test this on Excel 365 but I'm sure I've successfully used similar code in earlier versions.

This will add the suffix to all the selected cells.

```vb
Sub AddTextToEndOfCellValue()
Dim Suffix As String
    Suffix = "ID"
    With Selection
        .Value = Evaluate(.Address & "&""" & Suffix & """")
    End With
End Sub
```

This will add the suffix to the selected cells that have a value in them, as per the before/after image you posted.

```vb
Sub AddTextToEndOfCellValue()
Dim Suffix As String
    Suffix = "ID"
    With Selection
        .Value = Evaluate("IF(" & .Address & "="""", """"," & .Address & "&""" & Suffix & """)")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Does exactly what I was looking for, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the range is "A2:D5"

```
Sub AddSuffixinSelectedRange()
Dim rng As Range, newVal
Set rng = Selection
newVal = Evaluate("A2:D5&" & """_ID""")
rng = newVal
End Sub
```

This will replace values in place.. So better try it on a sample/ copy first.